# What are the options for an e-card wizard module?

Tags: 7

I am looking at creating an e-card wizard and would like to know if there are any modules that exist which would help with this.
A link should be added to a node and then the user should be able to create an e-card using information from this node. They need to be able to select a theme/image for the card, add a caption, add their email and the recipients email and then send it. Options to then share this with Facebook or Twitter etc should then be available.

Anyone done anything similar before?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ecards module](http://drupal.org/project/ecard)

As mentioned in the page, you can see a demo on http://www.mahlove.com/friendship-day/friendship-day-ecards/160